# Current work on molecular manufacturing

Tags: molecules, nanoscience

How much work is currently being done on molecular manufacturing (a.k.a. Drexler-style nanotechnology)? Or for that matter, is any at all being done? A Google search has turned up some what-if papers and comments by boosters and detractors, but I haven't been able to find anything of the form 'this laboratory is working on trying to actually achieve molecular manufacturing by the following route' or even 'corporation X is investing $Y'.

Comment: "Drexler-style nanotechnology" is somewhat undefined, since even his Nanosystems contains some very different approaches in the later third.

Comment: I know there are actual projects working on atomically precise manufacturing (or tools for doing it) in the process of getting funding. A lot of it is not called nanotechnology but DNA origami or protein manufacturing. But I do not have a proper list of names in my head right now.